# Custom YAML configuration file in Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to create a custom configuration file outside of `config/packages`, as I need this file to be writable. I understand that Symfony 4 does not define an AppBundle like previous versions. I've seen similar issues with solutions that does not work for my specific case.

So far I have created the following files:

```
# config/settings.yaml

settings:
    foo: 3
```

```php
<?php

namespace App\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\TreeBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ConfigurationInterface;

class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $tree_builder = new TreeBuilder();
        $root_node = $tree_builder->root('settings');

        $root_node
            ->addDefaultsIfNotSet()
            ->children()
                ->scalarNode('foo')
                    ->defaultValue(1)
                ->end()
            ->end()
        ;

        return $tree_builder;
    }
}
```

```php
<?php

namespace App\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;

class SettingsExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../../config'));
        $loader->load('settings.yaml');

        $container->setParameter('settings.foo', $config['foo']);
    }
}
```

And I've loaded the extension in `Kernel.php` as:

```php
    protected function configureContainer(ContainerBuilder $container, LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
        $container->registerExtension(new SettingsExtension());
        $container->loadFromExtension('settings');

        ...
    }
```

But if get the following error:

```
There is no extension able to load the configuration for "settings" (in src/DependencyInjection/../../config/settings.yaml). Looked for namespace "settings", found none
```

Answer (score 0):

You take the problem by the wrong end.

> as I need this file to be writable

If some along the (deployement?) processes you want to modify configuration before cache generation, the permission problem is an OPS problem. Surely you can't find a way to put the config/services.yml writable by using the right permission system.
Parameters files were replaced by `.env` file and environnement variables, you could write them?

If the mean is to put change global parameters it would be so much easier via database (looks at [CraueConfigBundle](https://github.com/craue/CraueConfigBundle)).
Yaml files are putted in cache. it means dynamically write yaml will fail in prod.